# Normal-Log transformation of the data

Tags: python, model, regression, transformation

I have the following dependent and independent variables for my linear regression model. Since they are all in different scales (some of the are % others continuous variables), I was suggested to take the log and normalize them before running the regression.

```
    Y    X2        X3 (%)       X1 (%)
Mean 2.9 24.6   0.009517    230.992248
std  2.3 32.2   0.077092    230.992248
Min  0   1      0           0
Max  8   539    1           1
```

I have the following Qs:

Why should I take the log and then normalize them - rather than using just one of the two data transformations?

Should I log and normalize also my Y variable?

How would interpret my coefficient at the end of the exercise? and how can I make them humanly intelligible for a business audience?

Any easy doc reference is very appreciated!

Comment: One advantage of log transformation would be decreasing the variablility in the data for some cases. Anyway this is not a SO question. You will get better answers in https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suggest making a test with normalization only, no logs, and see if the fitting results are sufficient for your purpose. The test is easy to make. You can also plot each independent (X) variable versus the dependent (Y) variable to see if any logarithmic relationships are apparent. This is also easy and fast to perform.